# .xcodeproj does not get committed with Xcode's SCM Tool

Tags: iphone, svn, xcode, version-control

I am using the SCM Tools embedded in XCode to manage my app's versioning.

I have created an iPhone app and I have added/committed it to the Subversion server but the .xcodeproj file won't upload (all the class files, resources etc are there)! I don't even get the option to "Add to Repository". Sometimes it gets an "A" (add) next to it under the "SCM" column but still, the next time I commit changes or commit entire project it still doesn't upload and show up on the server. As a result my team can't get and run the project.

Is there a way to so something (other than just use the terminal or Versions)?

Thank you.

Comment: No replies here as you can see. It's a bit buried now.
What I do now is use SVN in the terminal to manage my code. So I don't use Xcode's SCM directly.

Answer (score 3):

`<project>.xcodeproj` is actually a directory. The project data is stored in `<project>.xcodeproj/project.pbxproj`. Note that there are also some other relatively unimportant files in .xcodeproj which you don't need to worry about - just make sure that `project.pbxproj` gets checked in.

Comment: In fact, make sure *not* to check in those other files, because they are user-specific.

Comment: @WhirlWind: good point - it's annoying when people inadvertently check in these files

Answer (score 0):

The best way is to checkout the latest version from SVN and make/copy the changes to the file(s) and commit it.